# How can I make these two divs box shadow appear as one?

Tags: html, css

I have a banner right above a navigation menu.  The two have their own container divs going horizontally across the screen.  I have box shadows on both of them to make it look like outer glow.  The issue is that the shadow breaks(as it's meant to) between the banner and the navigation.  Is there any way that I can modify my code to make it look like the shadows are one?  Thanks for your time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeJal.gif

My HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blah Blah</title>
        <link href="assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapperOuter">
            <header>
                <div id="bannerContainer">
                    <div id="banner">
                        <h1>Scott <span class="green">H.</span> Lacey</h1>
                        <p>Web Developer <span class="green">&spades;</span> Photographer <span class="green">&spades;</span> Musician</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="toolbarContainer">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html" title="My Blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio.html" title="My Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html" title="My Services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="resume.html" title="My Resme">Resume</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html" title="About Me">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div id="toolbar">
                        <div id="social">
                            <label>Connect With</label>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Scott on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Scott on Twitterk"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Scott on Instagram"><i class="fa fa-facebook-"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Scott on LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="search">
                            <form action="#" method="POST">
                                <input type="text" name="searchCriteria" size="30" placeholder="Enter search text, then press enter.">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
span.green {
    color: #66cc00;
}
body {
    background: url(../img/bodyBackground.gif) repeat-x #000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #666666;
}

a {
    color: #66cc00;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #66cc00;
}
a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}
#wrapperOuter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#bannerContainer {
    background: url(../img/themeSprite.gif) 0 0px;
    height: 148px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#banner {
    background-image: url(../img/themeSprite.gif);
    background-position: 0px -210px;
    height: 148px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 960px;
    border-width: 0px 1px;
    border-color: #666;
    border-style: solid;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 26px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-align: center;

}
#banner h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#banner p {
    color; #999;
}
#toolbarContainer {
    background-color: #222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 26px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-image: url(../img/themeSprite.gif);
    background-position: 0px -153px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 52px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0px -5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
    height: 52px;
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}


#toolbar {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#social {
    float: left;
}
#social label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#social ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#social ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
#social ul li a {
    color: #666;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#search {
    float: right;
}

#search input {
    background: #333;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 26px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #666;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: wrap both divs with a single one and place the shadow on that one, looks like you might be able to just do that with wrapperOuter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes but you'd need to rewrite your code and place the nav menu and center head banner in a wrapping div element then apply the shadow to that element. Right now you have 2 elements which are going to be stacked on one another.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
        <style>
            .main {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .box1 {
                margin: 0 -2px;
                width: 50%;
                height: 400px;
                background: red;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .box1inner {
                margin: auto;
                width: 70%;
                height: 50px;
                background: blue;
                -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                -moz-box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            }   
            .box2 {
                margin: 0 -2px;
                width: 50%;
                height: 400px;
                background: orange;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .box2wrapper {
                margin: auto;
                width: 70%;
                -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                -moz-box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                box-shadow: -4px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            }
            .box2inner {
                height: 50px;
                background: blue;
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="box1">
                <div class="box1inner">
                </div>
                <div class="box1inner">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <div class="box2wrapper">
                    <div class="box2inner">
                    </div>
                    <div class="box2inner">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code above is how you are supposed to set up the div elements in order to achieve this. The left column will showcase your current issue and the right column shows the solution method.

I'd also advise you read heavily in CSS basic and DOM outline methods as you're going to have extreme issues down the road if you're planning to be a web designer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the drop shadows off of `.bannerContainer` and `.toolbarContainer`, then place a div around the outside of both of those and add the drop shadow there. You will have to put the `<div id="toolbar">` outside of this div too.

Comment: The problem with that is that the banner and the nav are both inside different parent divs.

Comment: The html is not set up to properly handle what you are asking, you have to refactor your code accordingly @ShoeLace1291 .